# Is taking notes or pictures of notes and using them for the answers consider cheating

Tags: halal-haram, sin, doubts, cheating

I’m having doubts if I’m cheating or not am I sinful

Comment: Let me get this straight: you're taking photos of notes and using them when you're not supposed to? Of course it is.

Comment: No my teacher said it’s ok but i still feel doubts that I’m cheating

Comment: if they allow you, it’s not cheating. If you’re still feeling uncomfortable, don’t use your notes.